# Angular 10 Send post request, then if successful call another request

Tags: angular, angular10

I have a register route, and a sign in route.
The register route will create a user on the backend.

If this call is successful I want to call the sign in route. This route will send back a user object.

/auth/register just registers the user and will send back an error if it does not work

/auth/sign-in will send back a UserModel if there is no error

How can I do this sequentially? Thanks

```
  registration(newUser: RegistrationUserModel) {

    // start of the registration process
    const options = {withCredentials: true, 'access-control-allow-origin': "http://localhost:4200/", 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    return this.http.post(`${this.API_URL}/auth/register`,newUser, options)

       // what should I do here if not sending back object until sign in route?
       .pipe(map(user => {


        // start of the sign in process
   
        this.http.post<UserModel>(`${this.API_URL}/auth/sign-in`,   { email: newUser.email, password: newUser.password }, options)
        .pipe(map(returnedUser => {
         localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(returnedUser));
         console.log('auth.service.ts LOGIN this.userSubject.next(returnedUser);');
         this.userSubject.next(returnedUser);
         return returnedUser;
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log('error caught in registration login service')
          localStorage.removeItem('user');
          console.error(err);

          //Handle the error here
          return throwError(err);  
          })
         );


        // end of the sign in process
        // ---
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.log('error caught in registration service')
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        console.error(err);

        //Handle the error here
        return throwError(err);    
      })
    );
    // end of the registration process
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use rxjs `switchMap` operator.

After making the first rest call, sequentially waits for it to finish and uses the result of the first for the second call.

An example of use:

```
firstApiCall.pipe(
   switchMap(response => {
     // do whatever you want with response then
     // return the second rest call
     return secondApiCall(response.id)
    })
).subscribe()
```

If you need more clarification on the use of the rxjs switchmap operator I am attaching a page where it is explained in detail:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Comment: return this.http.post<any>(`${this.API_URL}/auth/register`,newUser, options)
       .pipe(
        switchMap(response => 
          {
          
// I am getting: ERROR TypeError: this.authService.registration(...).pipe is not a function

Comment: if you added the curly brackets you have to return the second rest call.

in this way :

switchMap(response => { return this.authService.registration(...).pipe }

Comment: I modified the answer to better explain your problem